# Conditional drop down list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have managed to do a conditional drop down list from another list – however I now can't seem to copy it down the 1000 rows I need it to work on.

For example, in column A the user would select either:

```
Fruits
Veggies
Other
```

Then in column B, the drop down list would be conditional upon what was selected in A. So if the user selected `Fruits`, the drop down list in B would be: `Apples, Peaches` etc. Or if the user selected `Veggies` in column A's list, the list in column B would be: `Corn, Beans` etc.

I did the formula and I have:

```
=INDIRECT($A$1)
```

in the Validation tab etc.

The issue is: I have 1000 rows going down, and I don't know how to copy it all the way down, as when I do it shows the same options.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the validation rule `=INDIRECT($A1)` to column `B` down to `B1000`. Removing the fixed row reference will resolve the problem.